# Will Appliance with Power Supply AC 100 -240 V 50/60Hz work in US?

Tags: power-supply, converter, step-down

I've got a new Japanese game system; I've had some in the past and used a step down converter to safely use them. That was a long time ago. The power supply for the new one I have reads:

```
I/P: AC 100-240V 50/60Hz 0.3A
O/P: DC 5V 2A
```

Will this work safely in a US outlet? Or should I get another step down converter?

Comment: [What does this article tell you?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_wiring_in_North_America)

Answer (score 1):

Given that wall power in the US is nominally 120V, 60 Hz — information that is readily found on the web — what do you think?